# Ubuntu's terminal-keyboard shortcuts for Dvorak

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, terminal, dvorak

**How can you see the settings of Ubuntu's keyboard shortcuts in terminal and then change them for USA Dvorak?**

I am using USA Dvorak and my keyboard shortcuts are for Qwerty in all terminal applications such as Vim. I have not found a terminal application which would allow me to see the keyboard settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `/etc/default/console-setup`, `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`, `man setupcon`.

Answer (score 1):

This is some weird Ubuntu goofiness. In your keyboard preferences, remove the standard US layout and close the keyboard prefs. Then add the US layout with USA variant. This seems to fix the fact that console does not understand the layout switch.